# Find out is property has SET accessor

Tags: c#-4.0

I am iterating through all class properties and need to find out which properties has only `GET` accessors and which both `GET and SET`. I tried to use `propertyInfo.GetAccessors()` but not sure how to find out from `MethodInfo[]` returned object what accessors assigned to property. Any ideas?

```
var type = typeof(Word2Pdf);
foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    MethodInfo[] methodInfos = propertyInfo.GetAccessors();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to know is whether the property can be written to, [`PropertyInfo.CanWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canwrite%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the easiest way to find out.

If you want to get a `MethodInfo` for the setter for further processing use [`GetSetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The parameterless overload only get public setters; the one with a boolean argument can also get nonpublic ones.